# English word meaning single line of details on an invoice

Tags: single-word-requests

An invoice consists of a header (customer, addres, date) and details (a list of purchased products). I am looking for a single English word meaning a single element from the list of purchased products on an invoice. "invoice_line" or "invoice_position" are not good because they are two words. "line", "position" or "element" are very general and can mean anything, not related to invoice. I'd like a person who sees this single word to have an idea what it means without also seeing the word "invoice".

Comment: 'Item' does dual purpose, as the referent of article in the set in question, and its written representation.

> **item**  
> 
> 1: a distinct part in an enumeration, account, or series

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/item).

Comment: By far, the most common term for this is [**line item**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line%20item). That's a "single word" inasmuch as it's a distinct noun that has its own dictionary definition. It's a single word in the same sense that *hot dog* and *ice cream* are single words. But if you're looking for a "single word" that has no space in it, there is nothing I know of that is even close to that specific meaning.

Comment: Row or entry if more meaning the line in the invoice than what it describes?

Answer (score 1):

In my line of work, we call it a line item. I don't know for sure if this is good for you.

Comment: what is your line of work?

Comment: "Line item" means the same, here, as "item" alone.

Why should 'customer, address, date' and what, be a lumped into a "header"?

No single English word means "single line of details on an invoice" nor much like it, more than the simple "item." What reason is there to make "item" exclude any details; not even, truly, price, however obvious that seems to most of us a separate element in the list or invoice. 

Much of the problem seems to be seeing "invoice_line" or "invoice_position" or "line", "position" or "element" as the same.

How could anyone not be thinking in terms of invoices?

Answer (score 0):

How about **purchase**? Is not an *invoice* a list of **purchases**, one per line with, e.g., a product descriptor, number of units purchased, unit cost, and total cost? A person who sees this single word -- **purchase** -- would definitely have an idea what it means without also seeing the word *invoice*.